# How do I know which configuration options to use to install the pg gem on OSX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, installation, heroku

I've gone through Google and Stackoverflow and have yet to resolve my issue with installing the pg gem needed to deploy my app onto Heroku.

I have installed Postgresql through Macport, but maybe I installed it under the wrong path?

I say that because I am getting the follwing when I do `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/user/local/bin/pg_config`:

```
extconf.rb:24:in ``': No such file or directory - /users/******/postgresql/bin/pg_config --includedir (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Or I didn't do a complete installation because I keep on getting this:

```
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/TonyNg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
```

How should I go about in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this great guide,

http://www.gregbenedict.com/2009/08/31/installing-postgresql-on-snow-leopard-10-6/

Works great on lion (10.7) too.

Had same error as you before.

The tip (in guide) about creating a database user for your own shell account will save you alot of trouble.

Hope you get forward.